# Make generic tooltip for combo box (usercontrol)

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, window, devexpress

I want to make tooltip setting for combobox  generic so ...
I created a usercontrol for combo box which inherits from DevExpress lookup edit control
and I try to set tooltip for this control from selectedIndex property but while accessing this I am not able to access items from combobox

I am doing something like this

```
combo.datasource = new List<string>( "ABC" );
combo.selectedindex = 0;
```

This called user control property selected index where I try to do something like this

```
set
{
   this.ItemIndex = value ;
   this.tooltip = this.items[value].Value; //this line fire exception for items are null
}
```

Any suggestions.......

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to [DataBind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) your combobox control before its items can be accessed. Try something like:

```
combo.DataSource = new List<string>(new string[] { "ABC" });
combo.DataBind();
combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```